# Каков род аббревиатуры ИГ ("Исламское государство")?

Tags: аббревиатура

Группировка "Исламское государство" (ИГ) объявила о создании на подконтрольных ей территориях Ирака и Сирии халифата.

Если далее в тексте употреблять аббревиатуру ИГ без родового слова *группировка*

*ИГ объявило (а) о начале операций в Пакистане и Афганистане*,

то каков будет ее род?

И нужно брать эту аббревиатуру в кавычки?

На какие правила надо ссылаться?

Comment: Род буквенной инициальной аббревиатуры (читаемой по названиям букв) зависит от опорного слова в расшифровке аббревиатуры: МГУ (университет) принял новых студентов; ЕСПЧ (суд) высказался; СНГ (содружество) выступило с инициативой; РПЦ (церковь) призвала к прекращению кровопролития. Аббревиатура ИГ, насколько мне известно, читается по буквам, а не по слогам. Опорное слово в ней - группировка, но смущает тот факт, что, в отличие от примеров на Грамоте, это название в кавычках  (то есть условное, а не реальное).

Comment: родовое слово здесь _группировка_, а не _государство_.

Answer (score 2):

На сегодня определенных правил, по которым можно однозначно определить род аббревиатуры  - нет.

Тем не менее существуют определенные рекомендации, с соответствии с которыми можно определить род той или иной аббревиатуры.

Согласно этим рекомендациям: Род звуковой инициальной аббревиатуры ***(читаемой «по слогам»)*** ***( ваш пример)*** зависит не только от рода опорного слова, но и от внешнего фонетического облика аббревиатуры, точнее – от ее концовки. Так, если аббревиатура оканчивается на согласный, то она может согласовываться по мужскому роду, несмотря на принадлежность опорного слова к женскому или среднему роду. Причем в некоторых случаях согласование по мужскому роду является единственно возможным. Например, только мужского рода слова вуз (хотя заведение), МИД (хотя министерство), загс (хотя запись). В некоторых случаях наблюдаются колебания: например, МКАД – мужского рода в разговорной речи, женского рода в стилистически нейтральных контекстах. В некоторых случаях согласование по мужскому роду невозможно: ГЭС, ТЭЦ – существительные только женского рода. О родовой принадлежности таких аббревиатур следует справляться в словарях.

Однако, как можно заметить,  большинство таких аббревиатур широко распространены я языке и хорошо известны. Но многие аббревиатуры из этого списка представляют собой исключения.

> Поскольку аббревиатура в вашем примере мало известна,то во избежания неясностей ( ИГ объявил/***о*** - в среднем роде можно понять,что объявление сделало государство, а не группировка. В мужском вообще будет неясно, кто сделал объявление; а некоторые могут счесть такое согласование  за ошибку) лучше ее согласовать в роде родовым словом  -  группировка.

Кавычки в данном случае не нужны.

Подробнее о рекомендациях, как согласовать аббревиатуры можете прочитать здесь: [Как правильно употреблять аббревиатуры](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_91)