# ФРС какого рода?

Tags: род

ФРС (Федеральная резервная система) США повысил (а) ставку.

Аббревиатура ФРС, как и МИД, может быть мужского рода или только женского?

Comment: [Повтор вопроса](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/413234/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%98%d0%93-%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be)

Answer (score 3):

Род аббревиатур определяется по опорному или родовому слову. В нашем случае опорным словом является "система" - ***женск. р.*** Обратите внимание: МИД - аббревиатура только ***мужск. р.,*** хотя опорным словом в этой аббревиатуре является **министерство.** Здесь род аббревиатуры сложился исторически, по традиции.

Comment: а если опорное и родовое слова разного рода?

Comment: Например, группировка "Исламское государство". Род аббревиатуры ИГ - женский по родовому слову (группировка) или среднего по опорному (государство)?

Comment: Поскольку аббревиатура в вашем примере мало известна,то во избежания неясностей ( ИГ объявил/о - в среднем роде можно понять,что объявление сделало государство, а не группировка. В мужском вообще будет неясно, кто сделал объявление; а некоторые могут счесть такое согласование за ошибку) лучше ее согласовать в роде родовым словом - группировка.